# How to validate allow minus(-) and only numbers in input textbox using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to validate in an Amount input field?

1. Allow minus (Negative) sign only once in the text box. For, eg, -10.00. Don't allow other special characters because it's an amount field.
2. It should not allow alphabet letters. Allow only numbers.
3. Decimal(.) should be only once in the text box.

Comment: Use `type="number"`

Comment: this will alow n number of minus sign and decimal also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've wrote this just now based on your conditions, test it below:

**Update:**
Modified to work both on jquery and in javascript inline

```js
// This is a middleware that takes as parameter "decimals" which is by default 2

currencyNumber = function(decimals) {

  if (typeof decimals !== 'number') {
    decimals = 2;
  }

  return function(e) {

    var input = $(this instanceof Window ? e : e.currentTarget);

    var value = $.trim(input.val());

    var hasNegativeNumber = value.substr(0, 1) === '-' ? '-' : '';

    var nextValue = value
      .replace(/\.+/g, '.')
      .replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');

    if (nextValue === '.' || (nextValue.length > 1 && nextValue === "00")) {
      nextValue = '';
    }

    var dotsFound = nextValue.split('.').filter(function(i) {
      return i.length;
    });
    var afterDot = '';
    var beforeDot = '';

    if (dotsFound.length > 1) {

      beforeDot = dotsFound[0];

      dotsFound.splice(0, 1);

      afterDot = dotsFound.join('');

      nextValue = +(beforeDot) + '.' + afterDot.substr(0, decimals);

    }

    if (nextValue.substr(nextValue.length - 1, 1) === '.') {

      input.one('change', function() {

        if (nextValue.substr(nextValue.length - 1, 1) === '.') {
          nextValue = nextValue.substr(0, nextValue.length - 1);

          input.val(hasNegativeNumber + nextValue);

        }

        $(this).off('change');

      })

    } else {

      input.off('change')

    }

    input.val(hasNegativeNumber + nextValue);

  };


}

// Here is where you call the middleware

$("#amount").on("keyup", currencyNumber(3));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  Test your number (bind is from jquery):
  <input id="amount" type='text' />
  <br /> Test your number (bind is from javascript inline):
  <input id="amount-inline" onkeyup="currencyNumber(3)(this);" type='text' />

</div>
```

Comment: yes its good.But this code not working in my page.Can u plz check where i did mistake?i pasted my code above code

Comment: @Diamond copy the function again, it wasn't adapted for html, i fixed it now, so your inline code should be this `onkeyup="currencyNumber(3)(this);"` , you need to call it again, with `this` this time. First pair of "( )" is the "currencyNumber" function, the one with decimals, the second pair of "( )" represents the function that requires `this` object. In jquery you didn't need to call the second pair of "( )" because jQuery does that and passes the `this` object to it by default.

Comment: copy the function again i changed it just now, or just replace the `if` with `if (nextValue === '.' || (nextValue.length > 1 && nextValue === "00")) {
      nextValue = '';
    }`

Comment: i need one more help.I have another field for mobile .In this field allows only numbers but space should allow .for eg: 055 789655 like this.

Comment: @Diamond it's out of context, you should make another post if you need a function for your mobile field. `currencyNumber()` is designed to format currency/moneyz.

Comment: today i cant able to  ask questions.thats why

Comment: Alright, leave a comment here with your requirements on how do you want the function to work and i’ll post it later.

Comment: <input id="customermob" placeholder="Mobile Number" class="form-control detailinfo" value=""> In this field allow only number ,not special char.In this field should allow n number of spaces.that all.there is no limit for numbers. any numbers can enter.

Comment: Check out this fiddle for your mobile function, i hope it suits your needs: https://jsfiddle.net/ron39ab5/

Comment: sure, what is it about ?

Comment: `one more help` , `one small doubt only` ? i can't help you with this mate, you better hit that search button on google. Have a nice day

Comment: It's working perfectly. Thanks @darklightcode

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:** I guess this is what you are looking for. Found this in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/7XLqQ/3/). No plugin needed.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" id="myInput">
```

**Javascript**

```
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");

input.onkeypress = function(e) {    e = e || window.event;
var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;

// Allow non-printable keys
if (!charCode || charCode == 8 /* Backspace */ ) {
    return;
}

var typedChar = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

// Allow numeric characters
if (/\d/.test(typedChar)) {
    return;
}

// Allow the minus sign (-) if the user enters it first
if (typedChar == "-" && this.value == "") {
    return;
}

// In all other cases, suppress the event
return false;
```

};

Comment: my requirement is not matching  with that examples.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/152sumxu/2/    this is matching but how to use this?is this plugin or?Exactly like this i want

Comment: without plugin how to do this?